# MongoDB Aggregation strange behaviour with $or and $text

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm currently facing quite a strange issue, i'm trying to pull from my database some data, based on a `$text` search and taking into account whatever permissions my user has: my data look like the following:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5fd0e0c3233c72895e6655c9"),
  "Entity" :
  {
    "Groups" : null,
    "Name" : "Terasse"
  }
}
```

I'm doing an aggregation query to both input the search my user queries and it's permissions values, fully formatted, the final query look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $text: {
        $search: "Terasse",
        $caseSensitive: false,
        $diacriticSensitive: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "Entity.Groups": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        },
        {
          "Entity.Groups": {
            "$eq": null
          }
        },
        {
          "Entity.Groups": {
            "$eq": []
          }
        },
        {
          $expr: {
            $anyElementTrue: {
              $map: {
                input: "$Entity.Groups",
                as: "group",
                in: {
                  $anyElementTrue: {
                    $map: {
                      input: [
                        "/"
                      ],
                      as: "userGroup",
                      in: {
                        $eq: [
                          0,
                          {
                            $indexOfBytes: [
                              "$$group",
                              "$$userGroup"
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

For a quick explanation, it first does the `$text` match to find the `"Terasse"` word in my database,
then run a second match stage to verify that my user can access this data.

My second match stage has an `$or`, which will first check if the data is correctly formatted before doing a special check to see if my user can access this data.

As you can see, this $or statement is checking that the `Groups` field of my data is: non-existing, null, or empty.

In this latter case, I would like to return this data no matter what authorization my user have and thus, not executing the very last `$expr` part at all

This aggregation will work perfectly fine if my Data has `"Groups": [ "/" ]` for example, but will fail with this error otherwise:

```
uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "$anyElementTrue's argument must be an array, but is null",
        "code" : 17041,
        "codeName" : "Location17041"
} : aggregate failed :
```

From my understanding, this error will happen **IF** the query will execute till the `$expr` part **AND** my `Groups` field is equal to non existing **OR** null **OR** empty, while it should be impossible because the `$or` statement should return the data as soon as it detects one of the mentionned case.

Finally, the most troubling part is that this second match stage will work perfectly with no errors at all if the first stage **IS NOT** a `$match` stage with a `$text` search

I am completely clueless now, is there an mongo expert that could give me a hand understanding what's happening ?

Thank you.

**EDIT** : as requested in comments:

this document will **not work** with the mentioned query

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fd0e0c3233c72895e6655c9"
  },
  "Entity": {
    "Groups": null,
    "Name": "Terasse"
  }
}
```

this document will **work** with the mentioned query

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fd0e0c3233c72895e6655c9"
  },
  "Entity": {
    "Groups": [ "/" ],
    "Name": "Terasse"
  }
}
```

also note that you cannot use mongoplayground to test this, as it requires to create a $text index before-hand (afaik, there is no way to do this in mongoplayground)

**EDIT 2**:

I am starting to believe that the mongo query system is quite broken when including `$text` stage, i've reworked the query like this to make sure that it was not due to the `$or` somewhat not working, and yet, it is still having the same error:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $text: {
        $search: "Terasse",
        $caseSensitive: false,
        $diacriticSensitive: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "Entity.Groups": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        },
        {
          "Entity.Groups": {
            "$eq": null
          }
        },
        {
          "Entity.Groups": {
            "$eq": []
          }
        },
        {
          $and: [
            {
              "Entity.Groups": {
                "$type": "array"
              }
            },
            {
              $expr: {
                $anyElementTrue: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$Entity.Groups",
                    as: "group",
                    in: {
                      $anyElementTrue: {
                        $map: {
                          input: [
                            "/test"
                          ],
                          as: "userGroup",
                          in: {
                            $eq: [
                              0,
                              {
                                $indexOfBytes: [
                                  "$$group",
                                  "$$userGroup"
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see in this new query, i'm adding an `$and` check TO MAKE SURE THAT "Entity.Groups" is indeed an array before moving to the `$anyElementTrue` section and yet, the same error applies.

**FINAL EDIT**
Thanks to `Ray's answer`: I've changed my query to the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $text: {
        $search: "Terasse",
        $caseSensitive: false,
        $diacriticSensitive: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "groupsMissing": {
        $eq: [
          [],
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$Entity.Groups",
              []
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "groupsMissing": true
        },
        {
          $expr: {
            $anyElementTrue: {
              $map: {
                input: "$Entity.Groups",
                as: "group",
                in: {
                  $anyElementTrue: {
                    $map: {
                      input: [
                        "/test"
                      ],
                      as: "userGroup",
                      in: {
                        $eq: [
                          0,
                          {
                            $indexOfBytes: [
                              "$$group",
                              "$$userGroup"
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

I've used another stage with the $addField as `Ray` mentionned but remove some of the previous/obsolete stuff, it is now working smoothly, will report if any side-effects re-occurs.

As a final note, i'm still unsure why the previous query that I've did didn't work, and why that solution does, but it seems like adding another stage to the query doing the sanitize checks and then having the second stage only checking the sanitized bool **IS WORKING** !

Probably it is related to the way mongo is executing the query.

I believe different stages HAS to be ran in a sequential way by mongo which is what I initially expected (though `$and` should also do that, by the documentation)

Having everything on a single stage is probably making mongo run the query quite differently than written in an effort to optimize it ?
That's all I can guess.

Comment: Please add a complete document with which the query works as expected and a complete document with which the query does not work as expected.

Comment: please, find in the edit section at the bottom of the post the two documents

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't recreate it. It appears it could you be something specific to your set up.

Comment: I use the docker image mongo:4, I did no other configuration except creating a text index

Comment: What server version was used?

Comment: You have anyElementTrue twice in the query making it unclear which occurrence the error is referring to. Edit the query to use anyElementTrue once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use $addFields to project some helper fields to make your life easier.

Here is the code I try to modify your version as least as possible.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $text: {
        $search: "Terasse",
        $caseSensitive: false,
        $diacriticSensitive: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      // flag to indicate Entity.Groups is null/missing/empty array
      "groupsMissing": {
        $eq: [
          [],
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$Entity.Groups",
              []
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      // make Entity.Groups an empty array to avoid $anyElementTrue error
      "Entity.Groups": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$Entity.Groups",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        // part of the code can be shorten
        {
          "groupsMissing": true
        },
        // the code should be the same as your version for the rest
        {
          $and: [
            {
              "Entity.Groups": {
                "$type": "array"
              }
            },
            {
              $expr: {
                $anyElementTrue: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$Entity.Groups",
                    as: "group",
                    in: {
                      $anyElementTrue: {
                        $map: {
                          input: [
                            "/test"
                          ],
                          as: "userGroup",
                          in: {
                            $eq: [
                              0,
                              {
                                $indexOfBytes: [
                                  "$$group",
                                  "$$userGroup"
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i'm currently testing this but it looks promising, could you provide more explanation on the first few sections ?

I'm not sure how the following is checking for all types of misconfiguration (null, empty, missing) ("groupsMissing" $eq..)

Comment: $ifNull will return an empty array if $Entity.Groups is missing or null. (or the original value if not null/missing) By comparing that to [], you get a boolean flag that will be true if $Entity.Groups is either null, missing or empty array. the second part of the $addFields is just assigning empty array value if its missing or null, which will not $match by later stages while being able to pass the $anyElementTrue error

Comment: Thank you Ray, i've edited my post to include the final query, thanks to your answer, could you check it and tell me if the way I reformatted it would be a problem in long-term ?

Comment: I would still sanitize Entity.Groups as empty array as defensive measure. To be honest, I cannot answer your core query about the behaviour of aggregation execution. My answer is more like a talk of experience that we figure out a robust solution by trial and error on fixing similar problem(not yet found related issue for past 3 years). So I am interested on if any side-effects found by you too :)

Comment: Thank you, my only problem is some code is having different path based on wether Entity.Groups is empty or null after retrieval, i'll add an issue to fix this and then but back Entity.Groups sanitized :)

Answer (score 0):

First, MongoDB provides arrays for storing lists of things. Splitting strings on separators in queries is 1) less performant and 2) more difficult than it needs to be.

With that said, I do not see anything in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/ saying the clauses will be evaluated in the order given. Therefore,

> while it should be impossible because the $or statement should return the data as soon as it detects one of the mentionned case.

... appears to be an incorrect assumption as to how MongoDB works.

Note that https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/ does reference short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: Agree on the $or, however as you can see in my edit 2, i've tried using the $and operator aswell and yet, it seems like it doesnt short-cut the second statement